# Python requests Authorization header with token (oauth2) FatSecret API

Tags: python, api, python-requests, http-headers

I'm trying to connect to the FatSecret API. Here's the link to the documentation they give for an oauth2 authorization: https://platform.fatsecret.com/api/Default.aspx?screen=rapiauth2#using-token-api

I've made it through steps 1 and 2 and now I'm stuck on step 3. I've managed to update the headers with  'application/json' but I'm not sure if my call includes the token I create. I get a response code 200 but then an error message:
{'error': {'code': 21, 'message': "Invalid IP address detected:  '51.7.45.XX'"}}

```
params = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': 'REMOVED',
    'client_secret': 'REMOVED',
    'scope': 'basic',
    'method' : 'foods.search',
    'search_expression' : 'toast',
    'format' : 'json',
}

api_url = 'https://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api'


response = requests.post(api_url, headers={'content-type' : 'application/json', 'Authorization' : 'Bearer {}'.format(data['access_token'])}, params=params)
```

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27EZn.png)

Comment: Did you put your real secret_keys? you might want to delete&change them.

Answer (score 0):

```
params = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': 'REMOVED',
    'client_secret': 'REMOVED',
    'scope': 'basic',
    'method' : 'foods.search',
    'search_expression' : 'toast',
    'format' : 'json'
}

api_url = 'https://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api'


response = requests.post(api_url, headers={'Authorization' : f'Bearer {data["access_token"]}'}, json=params)
```

Should do it

Comment: I now get an error saying missing parameter: method. I've also noticed that the content-type is back to xtml/text...

Answer (score 0):

You have to login into your fastsecret account and whitelist your local IP there. Once you add your IP to get whitelisted it takes around 1 hour to get approved.

This resolved the issue for me.